# Invalid AppId passed on token:

Tags: spring-boot, azure-bot-service, azure-sdk-for-java

I tried to test bot framework integration with Microsoft Azure bot service using the java SDK provided by Microsoft, I keep getting below error message **Caused by: com.microsoft.bot.connector.authentication.AuthenticationException: Invalid AppId passed on token:**
and when I test the App ID and Password using Microsoft Axure API login its work works fine.
Please any help.

Answer (score 1):

The above-listed error is caused due to invalid App ID, Password or Invalid URI

**Follow these steps to solve the above Error:**

1. In the Azure portal Go to **Bot Registration** > **Access Control** > **Assign the user of the bot**
2. Then, connect to a bot running locally, and select **Open bot**. Add the port number and paste the updated URL in the Bot URL bar. Don’t Provide App ID and Password in the Emulator.

> **Note**: Microsoft Bot emulator [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#test-your-bot-on-localhost) says that when you are running
> **localhost** with the correct port add the **localhost** with the correct
> port and ask you to keep an **empty app id** and **password**

If already have an app id & password in **web.config**. you must include it in the emulator also otherwise you will get the same **authentication** error.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-emulator?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=java#run-a-bot-locally

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#connector-to-bot

Comment: Hey @Afeez Olawale, had it solved your problem else you can share more details so I can troubleshoot?